# Prove that $G$ is solvable if $AB=BA$ for any subgroups $A$,$B$ of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Prove that $G$ is solvable if $AB=BA$ for any subgroups $A$,$B$ of $G$.

My attempt:

Since $G$ is finite, so by Jordan-Holder Theorem, $G$ has a composition series, i.e, there exists a sequence of subgroups $N_i$ such that

$1=N_0\le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots \le N_k=G$

with $N_i \unlhd N_{i+1}$ and $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is a simple group. In order to prove that $G$ is solvable, I just need to prove $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian. So far I have not used the property of $AB=BA$ for any subgroups $A,B$ of $G$. So I thought of using it in proving $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian. So let $N_{i+1}/N_i=\{aN_i : a\in N_{i+1}\}$. I wish to show that $(aN_i)(bN_i)=(bN_i)(aN_i)$ for any $a,b\in N_{i+1}$. However, I am stucked here. Can anyone give me a hint to continue from here?THanks

Comment: So by induction you can easily reduce to the case when $k=1$ and $G$ is nonabelian simple. By choosing $A$ and $B$ to be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, prove that there is a unique such subgroup, which is therefore normal, contradicting simplicity.

Comment: @DerekHolt: In your way, I guess no need for induction as all sylow subgroups become normal subgroup. Hence $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Yes that's right, and hence $G$ is nilpotent as you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $AB=BA$ if and only if $AB$ is a subgroup. Thus you know that product of any subgroups is a subgroup. Use induction on $G$. That is why you can say that any proper subgroup of $G$ is solvable.

**Solution:** Actually you can show more. $G$ must be nilpotent.

Assume not. Then there exist $M$ maximal such that $M$ is not normal. Let $M^g\neq M$. Then we must have $MM^g=G$. Thus $g=mn^g\implies g=mg^{-1}ng\implies g=nm\in M\implies M=M^g$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I did not get your hint. Yes, I can show that AB are subgroups. What will be the induction hypothesis on G? Do we induct that each N_k is solvable? Thanks.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include this information. As it stands it is not a complete answer (yes it is permissible to answer your own question).